# Jira Rest api V2: user search is not working with pagination

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to get assignable users for a project `/rest/api/2/user/assignable/search` with Pagination but it returns the same values everytime.
This seems to work fine if we are using V3 api.
Some people have reported the issue https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-71380.

It would be great if someone can suggest some workarounds.
Thanks

Comment: If the endpoint in Jira Cloud's v3 REST API is working fine, why don't you use it instead of the v2 one? Also, you have provided a link to a bug for Jira SERVER, which is a different product to Jira CLOUD.

Comment: We are trying to fetch user from Jira SERVER instance , hence cannot use v3 REST API @DavidBakkers